# iPhone not charging in Windows. Driver without iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, driver

On a Windows 8 machine, I've connected an iPhone 4s. Windows makes a audible chime for 'device connected', but doesn't allow charging in any USB port.

iTunes isn't installed, and cannot be installed at this time under corporate policy.

The iPhone shows as a generic device / toaster under Control Panel's Devices as below. The iPhone does NOT show as charging.

Is there a driver to install to ensure the iPhone is detected and can charge via USB *without installing iTunes*?

I've tried:

- forcing Windows Update

[image]

Comment: Is there anything installed on the target machine that would prevent use of the USB ports completely (even just for charging)? Are you able to successfully charge or power any other device or perishable through the ports?

Answer (score 7):

Just download iTunes, open the .exe file with winrar or some other similar software and then run the AppleMobileDeviceSupport(64).msi executable from there.

Comment: I got "Apple Mobile Device Service failed to start" error on install, but after hitting "Ignore" charging still works. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Hm, if your company denies access for installing iTunes, I doubt you would be able to tweak/install drivers. Having said this, you might want to try this to only install the needed driver without having to resort to iTunes: [Install iPhone, iPod Touch and iPad drivers without installing iTunes](http://www.copytrans.net/support/install-iphone-ipod-touch-and-ipad-drivers-without-installing-itunes/)

Answer (score 1):

No driver is needed on the iPhone side (nor should it be required on the PC end).

The iPhone - even if 100% totally dead - should present itself as a USB device that would like power to run. Once the charging circuitry starts, [on a Mac the iPhone asks for any high power ports to charge the phone more rapidly than a typical USB device](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4049).

This is basically something the computer does so your PC should just send the normal USB charge over the power lines. The charge will be slower, so you might power off the phone (or lock the screen) to let it use as little power as possible to maximize the charge from your PC.

Comment: The user states that his phone is not charging when plugged into his PC. I have encountered the same issue before on devices that did not have the correct drivers installed. Yes, the iPhone should attempt through USB to install it's own drivers without iTunes but the question indicates it's a corporate laptop, which may be preventing the automatic installation.

Comment: Most PC provide 500 mA to all USB before it even scans to determine the device type iirc so either the phone is too low on power to even run or perhaps it's an odd computer that does need a driver to even enable USB power in some cases.

Comment: Again, I've encountered this on other PCs where the driver was uninstalled or somehow damaged, including my own MacBook Pro immediately after installing Windows 8 when I accidentally cancelled the automatic driver installation. While I agree with you that most devices are able to receive power off the USB bus, I'm also familiar with the issue the user is having. Sadly your answer is simply not correct for this case, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Windows is "stupid" and has typically installed the wrong driver. Yes, over the Apple driver and yes, it does this regularly.

Among other things, drivers decide how much, if any, power is available to plugged in USB devices.

The fix is to remove Window's drivers and upgrade them to the Apple one:

## To remove Microsoft's broken driver

1. Go to the Start menu via <kbd>Win</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>
2. Type "Device settings" to go to the *app* that manages drivers
3. Locate, under "Other devices" the device called "iPhone" with "Driver problem"
4. Remove the driver

## To install Apple's correct driver

1. Go to the Start menu via <kbd>Win</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>
2. Type "Device Manager" to go to the *windows app* that manages drivers
3. Locate, under "Portable devices" the device called "iPhone"
4. Right click and choose "Update driver software..."
5. Choose "Browse my computer for driver software"
6. Search for driver software in this location

   ```
    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support\Drivers
   ```
7. Next/Finish

Note: you need to install iTunes to have the drivers in that folder (I think)

Comment: This is the coolest and the easiest answer that I have found so far for this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the driver is not installed properly, the phone will not be detected by the computer and if that happens, the phone will not charge.
Make sure drive is installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

under devices and driver, simply remove the iphone then unplug it and plug it back in

Comment: It would be useful if you could explain this with more details. As it is, it's unclear as to what the user should do with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Went to the suggested location (see post below) and let Windows search for an update for this driver online. It found it, updated it, and then the iPhone began charging.

No iTunes installed on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just download iTunes, open the .exe file with winrar or some other similar software and then run the AppleMobileDeviceSupport(64).msi executable from there.

If you receive an "Apple Mobile Device Service failed to start" error, run the AppleApplicationSupport(64).msi executable as well. Otherwise, you may have issues such as the iPhone prompting you to trust the computer every time it is connected.